# Grails GORM class with @GrailsCompileStatic annotation shows in the static mapping closure table, version, autoTimestamp as unresolved symbol

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, grails-domain-class

References:

1. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206196
2. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207415?_ga=2.103698112.1724644326.1581075934-247190714.1566820331

```java
package de.equeo.requestcode

import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
class Feature {

    String name

    static mapping = {
        table 'rq_feature'
        version false
        autoTimestamp false
    }

}
```

This results in the error in the IDE only (works fine in `grails run-app` or while compiling):

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing that you can use the built in type safe dsl added in GORM 6.1

```
import static grails.gorm.hibernate.mapping.MappingBuilder.*

class Book {
    String title

    static final mapping = orm {
```

Comment: Oh! this is awesome. I knew something must be there in Grails and you showed up. Thank you so much for for this.

Comment: The new mapping builder looks really cool.  I understand the Grails team is swamped but it would really help it get adopted if there was some additional examples in the documentation and/or a shortish blog post that showed up on google when searching for this.

Answer (score 1):

I never spent much time before to figure out a workaround for this, but now I have a workaround.

## First Workaround (Recommended)

As **@JamesKleeh** answered, you even don't need to define the above method for type-safe DSL:

```java
package com.wizpanda.hooman

import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

import static grails.gorm.hibernate.mapping.MappingBuilder.orm

@GrailsCompileStatic
class User {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    String bio
    String email

    static final mapping = orm {
        table "rq_feature"
        version false
        autoTimestamp false
        property("bio", [type: "text"])
        property("firstName", {
            column([name: "fn"])
        })
    }

}
```

## Second Workaround

I used my own logic of this from https://github.com/wizpanda/kernel/blob/v2.1.6/src/main/groovy/com/wizpanda/logging/KernelLogging.groovy#L63 and created a static method `applyFooMapping` which uses `@DelegatesTo` annotation to fool the IDE

```java
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic
import org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder

@GrailsCompileStatic
class Feature {

    String name

    /**
     * This is to solve the IntelliJ Idea problem as defined
     * @param delegate
     * @param closure
     * @return
     */
    static applyFooMapping(Object delegate, @DelegatesTo(HibernateMappingBuilder) Closure closure) {
        closure.delegate = delegate
        closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        closure.call()
    }
    
    static mapping = {
        applyFooMapping(delegate) {
            table 'rq_feature'
            version false
            autoTimestamp false
        }
    }

}
```

Cheers!

## Third Workaround (Improvement to 2nd)

To solve this problem for multiple domains, create a groovy class in `src/main/groovy/some/package/AbstractFooDomain`:

```java
@GrailsCompileStatic
abstract class AbstractFooDomain {

    /**
     * This is to solve the IntelliJ Idea problem as defined
     * @param delegate
     * @param closure
     * @return
     */
    static applyFooMapping(Object delegate, @DelegatesTo(HibernateMappingBuilder) Closure closure) {
        closure.delegate = delegate
        closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
        closure.call()
    }
}
```

And now, use it in your domain classes:

```
@GrailsCompileStatic
class Feature extends AbstractFooDomain {

    String name

    static mapping = {
        applyFooMapping(delegate) {
            table 'rq_feature'
            version false
            autoTimestamp false
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Cheers again!

[image]

Comment: When I tried "Third Workaround (Recommended)" I started getting these Hibernate changes:

`Hibernate: alter table contact add column owner bytea not null`

`Hibernate: alter table question add column owner bytea not null`

`Hibernate: alter table question_file add column owner bytea not null`

This was a big step backwards for me..

Comment: My code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489171/grails-domain-object-sort-mapping-not-working) on SO.  I tried your workarounds but in my case, using IntelliJ 2019.1.3, the presence of @GrailsCompileStatic triggers these errors.  When I comment out the annotation the suggested workaround does not work.